# Does anyone know how to install a single node instance of Riak?

Tags: riak

Does anyone know how to install a single node instance of Riak as the documentation is plain wrong and I have been trying for over a day now?

Answer (score 3):

Try this tutorial: http://megam.info/2010/01/20/riak-strapping-up/

Comment: Mihai, you are the man! This worked first time!!!!

Comment: Looks like that post has moved to: http://cloudbuzz.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/riak-strapping-up/

Answer (score 2):

You can start a single node with

bin/riak start

Can you explain what is wrong in the documentation and what documentation you are using so that I can get it updated?

Comment: http://riak.basho.com/basic-setup.html

./start-restart.sh is not part of Riak anymore is it? I thought it was from an old release. Anyway, it is quite confusing when I google on Riak. It may be a good idea to always state the version number of Riak in the documentation

Comment: http://riak.basho.com/basic-setup.html

Comment: that doc is outdated, I'm working on getting all of the docs updated shortly. Sorry for any confusion. If you read the README in the source it explains things better.

Comment: this is the doc you want

http://hg.basho.com/riak/src/tip/README